# Escape colon in HQL (to use geography::STGeomFromWKB(...))

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I hope someone can give me a hint related to fluent NHibernate usage. I can't get the following code block working, due to the fact that the colons are treated as parameters. Is there any way to escape them?

```
_session.CreateSQLQuery(
  "insert into disposal_site"
  + "(geom, description) "
  + "VALUES (geography::STGeomFromWKB(:wkb,4326), :description)")
  .SetBinary("wkb", entity.wkb)
  .SetString("description", entity.description)
  .ExecuteUpdate()
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Best regards,
martin

Comment: have you tried \:\: or :::: ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution (not tried) would be registering your function with a name that doesn't have the colons.

You do that by inheriting from the corresponding dialect (for example, [MsSql2008Dialect](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/MsSql2008Dialect.cs)) and using `RegisterFunction` in the constructor.

Comment: Good hint but couldn't get it working so I shifted the work to the database and created a PL/SQL function which does the work. Switching the underlying causes more effort this way but this shouldn't be done that often anyway ;-)